# Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, phonenumberutils

[image]

How to cast this ?

Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'Bool'

[image]

Comment: please share the isPossibleNumber function

Comment: (BOOL)isPossibleNumberString:(NSString *)number
             regionDialingFrom:(NSString *)regionDialingFrom
              error:(NSError **)error;

Comment: Always post code as text, not as pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the [documentation](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS), it's throwable function, so in swift you can use like these ways

```
   guard let instance = NBPhoneNumberUtil.sharedInstance() else { return }
    do {
        try instance.isPossibleNumber("6766077303", regionDialingFrom: "AT")
        print("its valid, continue to process")
     } catch {
        print("not valid", error)
 }
```

or

```
guard let instance = NBPhoneNumberUtil.sharedInstance() else { return }
if let _ = try? instance.isPossibleNumber("6766077303", regionDialingFrom: "AT") {
    print("its valid number")
} else {
    print("there is no validity")
}
```

If you want to see the error case change `AT` with `AAT` and see how it works, I would prefer the second usage, so you can establish your logic with `if-let` blocks

Comment: I doubt the second approach is valid. `isPossibleNumber` has no return value in Swift so the use of `if let` won't compile.

Comment: after i've tested it compiled and worked, you can test it after installing with the pods or something else

Comment: Did you use the actual Objective-C code or did you make your own version in Swift to test with? The Objective-C method bridged to Swift will not have a `Bool` return value. It will be `Void`.

Comment: after installing it with cocoapods, i've used 2 approach, each of them is above, the situation that you asking returning void for success and throws for another cases